# Disabling background or all controls on a ASPX page using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

I am using this code to show a dialog box that will confirm for a delete button, it works fine, but when it pops up it doesn't disable any controls of ASP.Net page, so I can click on any of the controls or text boxes,

First thing I wanna do is fade out the page when Jquery opens my Div tag BOX and second to disable all the controls.

here's the code

**Div (Custom Dialouge box)**

```
    <div id="divConfMessage">
        <div align="center">
            <br /><asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="Deleting this eDecision will remove all site content and uploaded documents. Are you sure you wish to continue?" CssClass="headertext"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnConfOK" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click" Runat="server" Text="Yes"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Button ID="btnConfCancel" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" Runat="server" Text="No"></asp:Button><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
</div>
```

**Script (jquery)**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[id$='btDelete']").click(function() 
        {
        $("#divConfMessage").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Button**

```
    <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click"
    OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Please Wait...';" Text="Delete" Width="200px"  />
</td>
```

**Css for Dialog Box**

```
    #divConfMessage
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-left: -150px; /* Negative half of width. */
    margin-top: -100px; /* Negative half of height. */
    border: 2px solid #000;
    DISPLAY:none;
    background-color:White;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Note**

All of the code is in ASP content place holder for the page except CSS, I have 2 another Contents with different controls + a Master Page defining all these Content Place holders.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSubmit" runat="server">
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/my.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="c.aspx.cs" Inherits="a.b.c" Title="e"  meta:resourcekey="PageResource1"  %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Modal=true; for dilogbox there is modal property, you can set it as True.

try using [Jquery dialogue box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message) ( it comes with JqueryUI plugin).

```
$( "#YourDivorContainerToShowAsDialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

EDIt: if you don't want to use buttons, then use like this

```
  $( "#YourDivorContainerToShowAsDialog" ).dialog({
                modal: true             
            });
```

or if you want to use CSS then you can try

```
#YourDivorContainerToShowAsDialog 
{
position: absolute;
Z-index: withMaxValue
}
```

Comment: Hey Ravi, thanks for your answer, I already tried it, but my Div already have a asp.net buttons, so dont wanna use dialog buttons + it becomes really confusing then

Comment: @TimeToThine you can ignore buttons. only use modal property. so that your div will become modal box

Comment: thanks mate, i tried it but it still not disabling anything :|

Answer (score 1):

Give a higher **`Z-index`** for  `#divConfMessage` and then the modal dalog will be on top everything.

When you add a dialog append it to body as this way:

```
 add_block_page();
 add_modal_box();



function add_block_page(){
    var block_page = $('<div class="page"></div>');
    $(block_page).appendTo('body');
}

function add_modal_box(){
    var pop_up = $('<div id="divConfMessage"></div>');
     $(pop_up).appendTo('.page');
 }
```

Comment: for the Moment its on top of everything but just not blocking the page behind it :)

Comment: Change the background color from white

Comment: If i use your code of line, It Appends the body of the Div , not the page :|

Answer (score 0):

Use one transperant image to fadeout the page.

Add one outerDiv and apply the image to the div.

```
<div id="outerDiv"  style="display:none;">
<div id="divConfMessage">
        <div align="center">
            <br /><asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="Deleting this eDecision will remove all site content and uploaded documents. Are you sure you wish to continue?" CssClass="headertext"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnConfOK" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click" Runat="server" Text="Yes"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Button ID="btnConfCancel" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" Runat="server" Text="No"></asp:Button><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS for outerDiv

```
# outerDiv
{
top:0%;
left:0%;
position:absolute;
background-image:url('../img/FloatingPanel.png');//transperant image
color:White;
z-index: 1102;
Height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Give a higher Z-index for #divConfMessage than the Z-index of outerDiv(ie:1103). 
Show the outerDiv onclick of btDelete